# how to remove the first two elements and the last two elements of a list?

Tags: prolog

the following code is not possible, because it can only remove the first two or last two.

```
delements(L,L1):- append([_,_],L1,L),append(L1,[_,_],L).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not reuse `L1` and `L` in the same list. You need an extra variable here:

```
delelements(L, R) :-
    append(M, [_, _], L),
    append([_, _], R, M).
```

So here `M` is a list that contains the elements of `L`, except for the last two. `R` is a variant of `M`, except that the first elements are removed.

This then give us:

```
?- delelements([1,4,1,3,0,2,2,5], R).
R = [1, 3, 0, 2] ;
false.
```

Furthermore we do not need to use [**`append/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=append/3) to remove a fixed number of elements from the head. We can use unification for this:

```
delelements(L, R) :-
    append([_, _ | R], [_, _], L).
```

Answer (score 2):

```
trim(X,Y) :-
    append([[_,_],Y,[_,_]],X).
```